# Cutting disk into more than 8 parts of equal area by 4 lines

Tags: geometry, area, combinatorial-geometry

Is it possible to cut unit disk in more than 8 parts of **equal area** (possibly not congruent) by 4 lines?

It's can be proved that it's impossible to cut circle in 7 parts by 3 lines. For example, here is proof - [Dividing a disk into $7$ equal pieces with $3$ line segments](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1758/dividing-a-disk-into-7-equal-pieces-with-3-line-segments) .

My question is about what we can do with 4 lines.

So conjecture is that maximum number of parts of equal area for $n$ lines is $2n.$

Comment: Your title seems to be at odds with your question; the title is solved by 4 "pizza cut" lines meeting at the center; your question is about *more* than 8 regions.

Comment: Yes, I mean  "more than 8 parts". Title was updated, thank you.